# using AS field in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, mysql5

In the following example :

```
SELECT op.product_id, op.name, IF(op.sku <> '', op.sku, op.model) AS op_sku,
SUM(op.quantity) AS quantity
FROM order_product op GROUP BY op_sku ORDER BY op_sku ASC LIMIT 0,50
```

How can I use `op_sku` in WHERE clause? Do I need to add another select just to get the value I need?

**EDIT** original query :

```
SELECT op.product_id, 
       op.name, 
       IF(op.sku <> '', op.sku, op.model) AS model, 
       SUM(op.quantity)                   AS quantity,
       op.sku
FROM   `oc_product` p 
       RIGHT JOIN `oc_order_product` op 
               ON ( p.product_id = op.product_id ) 
       LEFT JOIN `oc_order` o 
              ON ( op.order_id = o.order_id ) 
WHERE  o.order_status_id IN( 17 ) 
GROUP  BY op.sku 
ORDER  BY op.sku ASC 
LIMIT  0, 50
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  The query doesn't make sense, because you have "bare" columns in the `select`.

Comment: Trying to get all order products with sku, if sku doesnt exist then model is used. The actual query is more complex.

Comment: Does the original query even _run_?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry my mistake, thats what I intented to do, not the actual query. Edited

Comment: You are aggregating by `op.sku`, but then _which_ values of the other columns in your select do you expect MySQL to use?  Do you see my question?  When you aggregate, you are taking groups of records for a given `op.sku` value.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thats why I needed to use the alias in the where clause, to group them correctly.

Comment: Can you show sample input and output data?  You current query does not make sesn

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use an alias defined in a `SELECT` clause in the `WHERE` clause of the same query, because it is not yet available at the time the `WHERE` clause is evaluated.  One option would be to just repeat the `IF` expression:

```
SELECT
    op.product_id,
    op.name,
    IF(op.sku <> '', op.sku, op.model) AS op_sku,
    SUM(op.quantity) AS quantity
FROM order_product op
WHERE IF(op.sku <> '', op.sku, op.model) = <some_value>
GROUP BY op_sku
ORDER BY op_sku
LIMIT 0,50
```

Another general option for dealing with this problem with be to just wrap your current query and then select from it.  In that case, the alias would be available:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        op.product_id,
        op.name,
        IF(op.sku <> '', op.sku, op.model) AS op_sku,
        SUM(op.quantity) AS quantity
    FROM order_product op
    GROUP BY op_sku
) t
WHERE t.op_sku = <some_value>
ORDER BY op_sku
LIMIT 0, 50
```

As a general comment made by others, your query might have an issue if you are selecting non aggregate columns while grouping by `op_sku`.  Ideally, either the other columns should be functionally dependent on `op_sku` *or* they should be wrapped in aggregate functions.  But the general answer I gave should be no less valid despite the same issues with the underlying query.

Comment: I'd just add that Common Table Expressions are coming in the next version of MySQL, which will create more options for handling this.

Comment: @BrianDewhirst Yes, and I have also heard that some basic analytic functions will be available.  I hope I don't have to edit all my MySQL answers.

Comment: The answer is right, but just the first phrase. The solution provided will not work, and apparently nothing will work in this case.

Comment: @yoda Your original query has problems, because you are selecting non aggregate columns while using `GROUP BY`.  You should really post the actual query, and we can take it from there.  Both the two options given in this answer and the suggestion by M Khalid below will get around the problem you described.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use custom aliases in where clause however these can be accessed through `having` clause

```
SELECT op.product_id, op.name, IF(op.sku <> '', op.sku, op.model) AS op_sku,
SUM(op.quantity) AS quantity
FROM order_product op
GROUP BY op_sku 
HAVING op_sku  = @somevalue
ORDER BY op_sku ASC 
LIMIT 0,50
```

You query is invalid and in newer version like 5.7 it will through you errors because product_id and name in select list are invalid either add these in group by or apply some aggregate function on them to get their values